# Retrieve JSON data with Angular

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to retrieve JSON data, which are publicly accessible, with Angular from a different domain, using the following the code. The problem is that it fails, throwing the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

This is my call:

```
MyMapper.prototype.find = function(params) {
        var p = angular.copy(params);
        p.limit = PAGINATION_LIMITS.MyResolver;

        var d = $q.defer();

        var requestURL = 'http://api.mydomain.de.dev/app_dev.php/api/search/foo.json?name=bar&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

        $http.jsonp(requestURL).
        success(function( results, status)
        {
           alert(status) ;
           for (var fooIndex in results.data.foo)
           {
               var preparedData = results.data.foo[fooIndex];
               results.data.foo[fooIndex] = new Foo(preparedData);
           }

           d.resolve(results);
        }).
        error(function(status)
        {
            d.reject(arguments);
            alert('Error');
        });

        return d.promise;
    };
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Just to add, that I am retrieving the data correctly as the callback tab in Developers tools suggest.

Comment: You don't have `fooIndex` declared should't it be `index` ? And one more thing, which line throws exception?

Comment: Sorry, that is fooIndex in for loop. Updated.

Comment: What about line that throws error?

Comment: The function gets into the Error block.
The error is happening -surprisingly for me- in the callback. However, I have checked the callback and it is valid JSON.

Comment: Any guesses on that? Still stuck and I cannot see any obvious reasons right now.